# How to add a custom Time Picker Dialog from an external library?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog, datetimepicker

I am using [this](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-datepickers) library to use custom time picker in my app. The relevant code from the `TimePickerDialog` class is as follows:

```
public static TimePickerDialog newInstance(OnTimeSetListener callback,
        int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourMode) {
    TimePickerDialog ret = new TimePickerDialog();
    ret.initialize(callback, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourMode);
    return ret;
}
```

Now in my activity I use this code to create an instance of the TimePickerDialog class:

```
TimePickerDialog dialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance((OnTimeSetListener) mTimeSetListener, getHour, getMinute, true);
```

Now I have to use the `dialog.show()` function.
But in the previous code, it show an error `cannot resolve method instance(...)`

My callback function is as follows:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        setHour = hourOfDay;
        setMinute = minute;
    }
};
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: Complete error log: `Error:(59, 51) error: cannot find symbol method newInstance(OnTimeSetListener,int,int,boolean)`

Comment: Please post the complete error log

Comment: Only thing that could be cause this problem is wrong import. Please check if you are importing `com.android.datetimepicker.time;` not `android.app`. correct the import and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to import the library which you want to use in your app

```
import static com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog.*;
```

The code which is used to create a new instance of `TimePickerDialog` class may be misinterpreted by the compiler. Hence it needs to be altered a bit:

```
com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog dialog = new com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog();
dialog.newInstance((OnTimeSetListener) mTimeSetListener, getHour, getMinute, true);
```

Just add the full name of the class lest it may confuse this with `android.app.TimePickerDialog`